# How do i add a line which tells the code that i want the platforms to speed up once a loop of the level has been completed/

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class PlatformMoving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1.5f; //How fast the platforms are moving

    // use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // Every frame we look at the position of the ground and it is moved to the left
        transform.position = transform.position - (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // If the position of the ground is off the left of the screen
        if (transform.position.x <= -13.05f)
        {
            // Move it to the far right of the screen
            transform.position = transform.position + (Vector3.right * 53.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the loop you're talking about is the lines following the comment `// If the position of the ground is off the left of the screen`. The increase of the speed would be specified within the `if` statement that follows it, since that's where the cycle is occuring.

I'd refrain from calling it a `loop` btw, simply because it makes one search for a `for`, `while` or `foreach` loop when skimming the code, leading to confusion when one isn't there.

I've commented in your code where it would be located.

```
public class PlatformMoving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1.5f; //How fast the platforms are moving

    // use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // Every frame we look at the position of the ground and it is moved to the left
        transform.position = transform.position - (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // If the position of the ground is off the left of the screen
        if (transform.position.x <= -13.05f)
        {
            // Move it to the far right of the screen
            transform.position = transform.position + (Vector3.right * 53.3f);

            // Increase speed here
            // speed += x;
        }
    }
}
```